# Heroku deploy rails app errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

I just deployed my rails app but i cannot start app. After `heroku ps:scale web=1` I seeing that app was crashed.

Last application logs:

```
←[36m2013-06-21T09:23:23.207330+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output
←[36m2013-06-21T09:23:23.214381+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     defaults values shown above in this help message.
←[36m2013-06-21T09:23:23.214381+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2013-06-21T09:23:23.214607+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
←[36m2013-06-21T09:23:23.214607+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     See the README in the newly created application to get going.
←[36m2013-06-21T09:23:23.207330+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
←[36m2013-06-21T09:23:23.214381+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
←[36m2013-06-21T09:23:23.214381+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2013-06-21T09:23:23.214381+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
←[36m2013-06-21T09:23:23.207330+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit
←[36m2013-06-21T09:23:23.214381+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2013-06-21T09:23:23.214607+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Example:
←[36m2013-06-21T09:23:23.214607+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m     rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog
←[36m2013-06-21T09:23:23.214607+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2013-06-21T09:23:24.271458+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 0
←[36m2013-06-21T09:23:24.281002+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to crashed
```

**UPDATED**

my gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0.rc1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.0.1'
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Comment: What is in your Procfile?

Comment: Good question. I only start use heroku and rails. What is it? Where I can find it or I must add its?

Comment: The heroku cedar stack uses a file called Procfile in the root directory of your app to know what to run. Docs here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile At the very least you need web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT

Comment: Do you have clean master in git? Everything commited and pushed?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel yes, all commited and pushed. I checked out it.

Comment: Gemfile? + Rails version?

Comment: @MarcGreenstock I just added `Procfile` with `web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT`
but I getting error again
`artemf@WS-CHL108 /d/OtherProject/TestHeroku (master)
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling web dynos... done, now running 1
artemf@WS-CHL108 /d/OtherProject/TestHeroku (master)
$ heroku ps
=== web (1X): bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
web.1: crashed 2013/06/21 16:00:44 (~ 14s ago)`

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Rails 4.0.0.rc1

Comment: Attach gemfile & ruby version please. I think you need to user Ruby 2.0 for Rails 4 in heroku.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel see In updated, please

Comment: Check out heroku guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4-getting-started

Comment: First quick thing - you should add one heroku specific gem + set ruby version in Gemfile (heroku by default uses 1.9.2 which is not supported by Rails 4)

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel unfortunately, I just tried use 'ruby "2.0.0"' and after 'ruby "1.9.3"' but nothing happens.

Comment: bundle install first?

Comment: This is a completly new app? What happens if you follow the guide I linked step by step?

Comment: It's right now created app. Only rails generated code.

Comment: I tried created app from scratch once again. I followed instruction from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4-getting-started and didn't get error.
But on last step I get eroor again `=== web (1X): bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV
web.1: crashed 2013/06/21 16:52:34 (~ 30s ago)`

Comment: LAst thing I can think of - latest rails 4 is rc2, tried that?

Comment: Yes, I used rc1 but I changed rails version to beta1. This has no effect. Later, I to deployed app but from cloud9 ide [link](https://c9.io/). May be problem in my windows 7 environment.